# reading data with recursive functions

Tags: c

I am reading some data from file which are nested into each other (like a file tree) to put it into an array.

Reading is done well, but i am not able to put the array back into main(). The result of AnzGrid is 0, so the for-loop will not start.

Has anyone a hint for me how to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void read_include(int,int*,char*);

void read_include(int AnzGrid,int* GridIDs,char* Input){
    char Line[81];
    char* Token;
    FILE * File;
    FILE * File1;

    File = fopen(Input,"r");
    printf("opening %s\n",Input);

    if (!File){
      printf("%s not found here\n",Input);
      return;
    }
    if (File){
        while (fgets(Line,80,File)){
            printf("%s",Line);
            if (strncmp(Line,"GRID    ",8) == 0){
                Token=strtok(Line," ");
                Token=strtok(NULL," ");
                GridIDs[AnzGrid] =atoi(Token);
                AnzGrid++;
            }
            if (strncmp(Line,"INCLUDE ",8) == 0){
                Token=strtok(Line,"'");
                Token=strtok(NULL,"'");
                read_include(AnzGrid,GridIDs,Token);
            }
        } 
        fclose(File);
    }
    printf ("%i\n",AnzGrid);
    return;
}


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )  {
    char Input[81];
    int i;
    int AnzGrid; 
    int GridIDs[100];
    strcpy(Input,argv[1]);


    read_include(AnzGrid,GridIDs,Input);
    printf ("=>%i\n",AnzGrid);

    for (i=0;i<AnzGrid;i++){
    printf ("GridID: %i\n",GridIDs[i]);
 }
```

Comment: should be `void read_include(int *AnzGrid,int* GridIDs,char* Input){` and `int AnzGrid=0;`

Answer (score 2):

It's because when you pass arguments to functions they are passed *by value*, in other words the values of the arguments you pass are *copied* in the function. That also means that any changes you make to an argument inside a function are made on the copies, and those changes will be lost once the function returns.

There are basically two ways of solving this in C:

1. Return values from the function using `return`
2. Emulate [pass by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_by_reference#Call_by_reference) by passing a pointer to the data, and using the dereference operator inside the function.

The second alternative could require some example code:

```
/* Passing `AnzGrid` as a pointer */
void read_include(int *AnzGrid,int* GridIDs,char* Input){
    ...
    (*AnzGrid)++;  /* Using the dereference operator */
    ...
}
```

You call the function, *not* by declaring `AnzGrid` as a pointer, but by using the address-of operator:

```
int main(...) {
    int AnzGrid = 0;  /* Initialize */

    ...

    read_include(&AnzGrid,GridIDs,Input);  /* Note use of address-of operator `&` */

    ...
}
```

***Note:*** In the snippet of code for the `main` function, I also fix another bug you have, one leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior): You not initializing the `AnzGrid` variable. Local variables are not automatically initialized, instead their values are *indeterminate* (and will be seemingly random). Using an uninitialized local variable without initializing it leads to the mentioned undefined behavior. For example, if `AnzGrid` have an indeterminate value, what would `AnzGrid++` do and what would the result be?

Comment: Is it really a infinite recursion? The results (using th 2nd way) are ok and even for bigger data the runtime is rather short...

Comment: @Bruno My bad, removed last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Your `read_include` function should probably return a `malloc`-ed pointer to some `struct` containing the read data.

Of course you should adopt the convention that `read_include` is returning a heap allocated pointer, and `free` it *later* suitably.

BTW, you should compile your code with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and you should learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)